# Setting styles on primeNg radiobutton

Tags: css, angular, radio-button, primeng

I am trying to set a border around the selected radio button and its label using the primeNg style classes.
My HTML code is like:

```
<div class="p-d-flex p-flex-column">
  <p-radioButton
    styleClass="radio-style"
    class="p-col"
    [(ngModel)]="form"
    [value]="true"
    label="true"
  ></p-radioButton>
  <p-radioButton
    styleClass="radio-style"
    class="p-col"
    [(ngModel)]="form"
    [value]="false"
    label="false"
  ></p-radioButton>
</div>
```

and my SCSS is like:

```
:host ::ng-deep .radio-style.p-radiobutton {
  border: thin solid green;
}
```

However, the end result only looks like this :
[image: radio buttons].

I would want the green to be around the whole thing, not just the box itself, and only around the selected one. (for the second issue I tried using `p-label-active` but I don't think I did it right bc it didn't work)

How can I achieve the border around the label too, and how I can have it only on the selected radio button?

[stackblitz of the issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-k1emba?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

**EDIT:**
To clarify, the desired affect I am looking for is
[image: desired affect]

**EDIT 2:**
I found a workaround. Still looking for better answers if they exist.
Workaround: use custom class and ngClass, as seen in stackblitz update.

HTML:

```
<div class="p-d-flex p-flex-column">
    <p-radioButton [ngClass]="{'selected':form===true}" styleClass="radio-style" class="p-col" [(ngModel)]="form"
        [value]="true" label="true"></p-radioButton>
    <p-radioButton [ngClass]="{'selected':form===false}" styleClass="radio-style" class="p-col" [(ngModel)]="form"
        [value]="false" label="false">
    </p-radioButton>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.selected {
  border: thin solid green;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution ended up being a lot simpler - the class needed to be further out.

so, HTML:

```
<div class="p-d-flex p-flex-column">
  <p-radioButton
    styleClass="radio-style"
    class="p-col" [ngClass]="{'selected':form}"
    [(ngModel)]="form"
    [value]="true"
    label="true"
  ></p-radioButton>
  <p-radioButton
    styleClass="radio-style"
    class="p-col" [ngClass]="{'selected':!form}"
    [(ngModel)]="form"
    [value]="false"
    label="false"
  ></p-radioButton>
</div>
```

and then scss:

```
.selected {
     border: 2px solid green ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you close but you need to target .p-radiobutton-box class

```css
:host ::ng-deep .radio-style .p-radiobutton-box {
  border: 2px solid green ;
}
```

just to make the style reusable I will move the style to the global style file

*style.scss*

````css
.radio-style {
  .p-radiobutton-box {
    border: 2px solid green !important;
  }
}

update the selected style 
```css

p-radiobutton {
  .radio-style {
    .p-radiobutton-box {
      border: 2px solid green;
    }

    .p-radiobutton-box.p-highlight {
      border-color: red;
      background: orange;
    }
  }
}
````

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-k1emba-sfqjtu?file=src/styles.scss)